# How to query/limit a transclusion when including the talk page?

Tags: mediawiki, transclusion

As the tag implies, I am using MediaWiki as wiki-software. **I would like to include the talk page/discussion into the page the talk/discussion is about.**

I figured out how to include the talk page as a whole already doing something like this fo example (don't bother with the German notation): `{{Diskussion:Test}}` which add the talk page of the article *Test*.

The next step would be to limit the output to e.g. the 5 most recent talk "posts" (they are rather gouped under 2nd-grade headlines, I presume). Insertin of special pages can be limited by using additional parameters like so: `{{Special:RecentChanges/days=5,limit=40}}` as mentioned in MediaWiki help articles. However, these parameters obviously don't work when including the talk page because it is a single page/element. `{{Diskussion:Test/days=5,limit=40}}` is not even parsed.

Any hints and examples ae appreciated, although I prefer not to use extensions IF POSSIBLE.

Comment: This is not possible without an extension. The [relevant bug report](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T7881) contains a link to one such extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to edit [[Diskussion:Test]] by adding appropriate [noinclude (or onlyinclude) tags](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Noinclude.2C_includeonly.2C_and_onlyinclude):

```
<noinclude>
blabla
</noinclude>
== The ==
...
== sections ==
...
== I ==
...
== want==
...
== transcluded ==
...
```

Now {{Diskussion:Test}} won't transclude the older stuff. This is the cleanest solution but might be tedious to do on many pages: you could automate this with [a bot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot).

There are countless on-wiki solutions possible, for instance you could transclude everything and then use JavaScript to hide "excess" sections; or you could wrap all talk page discussions in a template, which then shows only the latest X when transcluded in subject namespace.

As for "proper" solutions, perhaps you're looking for a discussion extension. If you're brave you could test LiquidThreads, add threads directly on the page (rather than talk) and set up autoarchiving as you wish.

Comment: I discovered the usefulnes of bots a little later after posting the question. You are right about bots being the best choice. Editing the talk page will be denied for everyone except an administrative group and group of bots which are doing the main editing/date sorting. A posting-form will send such a bot to update the talk page appropietly. Later I could add a special kind of page which stores structural information about the talk pages to speed up sorting, as I am devloping not a typical wiki with gigantic content base but a moderate to small but highly strcutured one.